# SQL PIvot for a complex join

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlite, pivot-table, transpose

I have one table which captures name value groups for a manager. So for example, manager with id 1, has two group value pairs: location=dublin and dept=sales.

| GROUP | VALUE | MANAGERID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LOCATION | DUBLIN | 1 |
| DEPT | SALES | 1 |
| LOCATION | OSLO | 2 |
| DEPT | SALES | 2 |
| LOCATION | LONDON | 3 |
| DEPT | SALES | 3 |

I have another table which has employee groupings...

| GROUP | VALUE | EMPLOYEEID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LOCATION | DUBLIN | 101 |
| DEPT | SALES | 101 |
| LOCATION | DUBLIN | 102 |
| DEPT | SALES | 102 |
| LOCATION | DUBLIN | 103 |
| DEPT | SALES | 103 |
| SHOESIZE | 15 | 103 |
| LOCATION | OSLO | 104 |
| DEPT | SALES | 104 |

I want to get a list of all employees that at a minimum have the same groupings as a specific manager. So for example, manager with id 1, is location=dublin and dept=sales and the employees that have these group values at a minimum are 101,102 and 103 but not 104.

I don't know the values for group column or the value column in advance.   If I do a naieve inner join on the group and value columns and then a distinct, I get 101, 102 103 and 104

Any ideas?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `CROSS` join of the tables and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEEID
FROM managers m CROSS JOIN employees e
WHERE m.MANAGERID = 1
GROUP BY e.EMPLOYEEID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m."GROUP") = 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN e."GROUP" = m."GROUP" AND  e."VALUE" = m."VALUE" THEN 1 END)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2fe1b6c5f95cc2c5ab1180b5f6ff4d3f).
Results:

| EMPLOYEEID |
| --- |
| 101 |
| 102 |
| 103 |

Comment: very clever, but wondering will the outer join not just mean a table scan?

Comment: @MoreThanFive what do you mean? A table scan is necessary so that the groupings of MANAGERID = 1 are matched to the groupings of the employees. You could change the join to `FROM managers m INNER JOIN employees e ON m.MANAGERID = 1`, but this would not actually make it an INNER join.